# Write the function $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ as a power series, With center at $z=-1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to solve a question where I need to write $\frac{1}{z^2+1}$ as apower series with the center $z=-1$.

I solve the question as far as $$\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{1-iz}+\frac{1}{1+iz}\right)$$

Comment: The coefficients of a power series in $z+1$ can be expressed in terms of the derivatives evaluated at $z=-1$. As you have done the partial fraction decomposition, you should be able to find all those derivatives and get to the answer. But you should read up on how to format mathematics on this site. The is help via the Help menu.

Comment: Let me call $z+1=w$ to write less. Then $\frac{1}{z^2+1}=\frac{1}{(w-1)^2+1}=\frac{1}{w^2-2w+2}=\frac{1}{(w-r_1)(w-r_2)}$, with $r_1,r_2$ the roots of $w^2-2w+2$. Finally $\frac{1}{(w-r_1)(w-r_2)}=\frac{1/(r_1-r_2)}{w-r_1}+\frac{1/(r_2-r_1)}{w-r_2}=-\frac{r_2}{r_1-r_2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{w^n}{r_1^n}-\frac{r_1}{r_2-r_1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{w}{r_2^n}$.

Comment: I stil dont understand it, why are you using the roots in the question? why are you not using th partial fraction?

Comment: I am using partial fraction decomposition, but the one applied to the rational function expressed in terms of $w$ (which is $z+1$). I used names $r_1,r_2$ for the roots of $w^2-2w+2$ to not have to write the actual roots at each step. Only at the end you can compute the roots and substitute them in the final expression.

Comment: If you want to finish starting from your decomposition, then write each of your fractions in terms of $z+1$. For example, $\frac{1}{1-iz}=\frac{1}{1-i(z+1)-i}=\frac{1}{1-i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{i(z+1)}{1-i}}=\frac{1}{1-i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^n(z+1)^n}{(1-i)^n}$. The only difference is that I wrote the expression first in terms of $z+1$ (in terms of $w$) and then I decomposed in simple fractions. In your case you decomposed in simple fractions first. Then what you are missing is to write the expression in terms of $z+1$.

Comment: In both of them the final step is to write the simple fractions in the form $\frac{1}{1-\square}$ and use the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-\square}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\square^n$

Comment: Hi again! So you mean that the power serial of this function is 1/1−i=∑i^n(z+1)^n/(1−i)^n